# Can we get the attributes of a javascript class?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have this javascript class :

```
class UserDTO {

   constructor(props) {
       this.username = props.username;
       this.birthday = props.birthday;
   }
  }
```

and I have a class Utils that convert an Entity to DTO:

```
    class Utils  {

          convertEntityToDTO (entityObj, DTOClass) {
              // entityObj is an instance of a Entity,
              // DTOClass is a class not an instance
               let objDTO = new DTOClass();
               Object.getOwnPropertyNames(entityObj)
                    .filter(prop => DTOClass.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                    .forEach(prop => {
                        objDTO[prop] = entityObj[prop];
                    });
    }
}
```

this doesn't work a class ; hasOwnProperty just work with object; is a way to verify if a property is an attribute of a class or not ? or I have to create an instance to test ?

Comment: You could try using `objDTO.hasOwnProperty(prop)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hasOwnProperty` on the instance and `getOwnPropertyNames` :

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.ex = 'TEST';
  }
}

var a = new A();
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty('ex'));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a));
```

If instead you want the methods, you need to get the prototype:

```js
class B {
  constructor() {}
  
  exMethod() {
    console.log('test');
  }
}

var b = new B();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(b).hasOwnProperty('exMethod'));
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(b)));
```